# How to know if a perspective is changed in eclipse plugin project?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have an eclipse plugin project where multiple Perspectives are used. For eg, I have "Messages perspective" and "Reports Perspective". After performing some action in Reports Perspective, if i switch to Messages Perspective, how to notify the user about the unsaved changes in the Reports Perspective?

[image]

Comment: Editors are not bound to perspectives. Different perspectives have different views, menus, etc. Opened editors stay opened when switching a perspective.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a 3.x compatibility mode RCP (rather than e4).

You can use an `IPerspectiveListener` to listen for perspective changes:

```
IWorkbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();

window.addPerspectiveListener(....);
```

note that as well as the basic `IPerspectiveListener` you can implement `IPerspectiveListener2`, `IPerspectiveListener3` or `IPerspectiveListener4` for more information about perspective changes.